# Mount Intersystem cache database

Tags: database, collation, mount, intersystems-cache

I have intersystem cache database file (cache.dat around 160MB). From management portal, I created a new database which point to my file.

But when i go for mounting the file into database, it gives me an error -

ERROR #86: the database default collation is not available

Please help me on this.

For your information i am using intersystem cache version 2011.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that you either trying to mount Unicode database on 8 bit system (or vice versa) or you are trying to mount a database with collation that is not installed to your cache system. In the last case you will need to install a locale file with required collation. You can look into cconsole.log file in mgr directory to see if there is a better error description there.

Comment: I am unable to find any installation file for locale with all required collations. Is there any way i can upgrade the cache with all required collation.

Please help me no this.

Comment: Here is the exact error code/message

"Failed to mount c:\intersystems\trycache\mgr\nrad\ because its default collation (1280) is not available"

Btw, couldnt get a download for collation 1280, does some one have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Make a COPY, convert copy with cvendian:

```
noddy@chopin 11:24:36 /scratch3/noddy/chopin/mgr/db16k 
$ ../../bin/cvendian CACHE.DAT 
This database is little-endian.
This database has a block size of 16384 Bytes.

This database has 1 volume and 1 map.
The last block in the primary volume is 768.

Original manager directory is /home/isc/cache/mgr/db16k/

No extension volumes.

Done converting CACHE.DAT to big-endian
```

Hope this appears in a timely fashion

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I believe it was because I was trying to mount a database that was big-endian on a little-endian system (or maybe the other way around--doesn't really matter.) I'm not certain this was the problem, but it's the only difference I can think of between the two databases I was trying to mount.